# can't use appcfg.py update gae

Tags: python

recently i want to upload  GAppProxy to GAE.
but when i use the appcfg.py to update the files,there comes an error,it  was:
urllib2.URLError: urlopen error [Errno 8] _ssl.c:480: EOF occurred in 
violation of protocol
i don't know why
PS:i live in china,and may be because of the GFW.
and when i use the type :appengine.google.com and then input the password,i can't redict to the index page,there is an error too,which says:ssl error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030776/urllib2-urlerror-urlopen-error-10054-connection-reset-by-peer-on-gae), the issue is discussed [here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/738feae1c5d3dcd8/f1f214066b9a99db?lnk=gst&q=10054&pli=1) and the solution is to set proxies, e.g. in Windows on the command line:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://google.cn:80 
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://google.cn:80
```

(or however you set proxies for http and https on your platform, which you don't mention).

Comment: @user, good to know!  Then you should accept the answer (click on the checkmark-shaped outline on the answer's left) -- this is the official SO way to marking the answer that's been most helpful in solving your problem, rewards me with rep points for giving good helpful answers, and rewards you too a little for playing by the rules.  It's THE fundamental way SO works, so, play along!-)